# Getting a function to "wait" for values in multi-frame Tkinder app

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script that creates a build in TeamCity.  I am trying to create a gui that accomplishes this using Tkinder.  There are multiple steps to take (ie get credentials -> input buildname -> add template - > etc), so I am using multiple frames to create the steps using the `show_frame()` command.  My problem is the following: I make multiple REST calls, so the first step is getting the user's username and password.  However, since all the pages are initialized when the program starts, all my methods that make REST calls error because they don't have the credentials yet.

How can I get the subsequent steps (and their methods) to wait for the user to input username and password?

From the code below, (in the PageOne class) I am trying to get a list of projects from BitBcuket through a REST call so I can dynamically add menu items to a menu, but I can't figure out how to wait to get the username and password.

```
import json
import requests
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

TITLE_FONT = ("Arial", 18, "bold")


class CreateBuild(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
        self.bit_projects = None
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def authenticate(self, username, password):
        r = requests.head('https://source.amirsys-int.com/projects', auth=(username, password))
        if r.status_code == 405:
            self.username = username
            self.password = password
            self.show_frame("PageOne")
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "Incorrect username and/or password.\nPlease enter your Crowd username and "
                                           "password.")

    def get_bitbucket_projects(self):
        r = requests.get('https://source.amirsys-int.com/rest/api/1.0/projects', auth=(self.username,
                                                                                       self.password))
        j = json.loads(r.text)
        size = j['size']
        repo_dic = {}
        for i in range(0, size):
            name = j['values'][i]['name']
            repo_id = j['values'][i]['key']
            repo_dic[name] = repo_id

        self.bit_project = repo_dic


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        instructions = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter your Crowd credentials", font=TITLE_FONT)
        instructions.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3, padx=30, pady=30)
        username = tk.Label(self, text="Crowd Username: ")
        username.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
        password = tk.Label(self, text="Crowd Password: ")
        password.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=2)
        username_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        username_entry.grid(column=3, row=2)
        password_entry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        password_entry.grid(column=3, row=3)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Next", command=lambda: controller.authenticate(username_entry.get(),
                                                                                      password_entry.get()))
        button.grid(column=4, row=4, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        instructions = tk.Label(self, text="Enter build information", font=TITLE_FONT)
        instructions.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3, padx=30, pady=30)
        build_name = tk.Label(self, text="Build Name: ")
        build_name.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
        build_name_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        build_name_entry.grid(column=3, row=2)

        project_key = tk.Label(self, text="BitBucket Project: ", anchor="w")
        project_key.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=2)
        project_menu = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Project", anchor="w")
        project_menu.grid(column=3, row=3, columnspan=2)
        project_menu.menu = tk.Menu(project_menu)

        for key, value in controller.bit_projects:
            project_menu.menu.add_checkbutton(label=key, variable=value)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CreateBuild()
    app.geometry("800x600")
    app.title("Create TeamCity Build")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If your problem is related to the fact you're creating all the pages at once, have you tried waiting to create the pages until after you have the data?

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry, I am a little new at this, but I thought I had to have all the pages initialized when the program runs?  if not how do i create them after?

Comment: In this specific code that you copied, yes, the pages have to be created first. There are many other ways to create the pages. It's important to understand code that you've copied from someone else, and not use it without first understanding how it works. Unfortunately, you've copied some advanced code that isn't very good for beginners to use.

Comment: @BryanOakley I understand it just fine. I asked for help not a lecture.

Comment: If you understood it, you would realize there's nothing requiring you to create all the classes up front. They are only created up front in this example because it was a convenient way to illustrate how to switch between pages in a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move that code out of the __init__ method (which runs when the program starts) and into the method that gets called when the frame is shown: tkraise().

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        instructions = tk.Label(self, text="Enter build information", font=TITLE_FONT)
        instructions.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3, padx=30, pady=30)
        build_name = tk.Label(self, text="Build Name: ")
        build_name.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
        build_name_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        build_name_entry.grid(column=3, row=2)

        project_key = tk.Label(self, text="BitBucket Project: ", anchor="w")
        project_key.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=2)
        self.project_menu = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Project", anchor="w")
        self.project_menu.grid(column=3, row=3, columnspan=2)
        self.project_menu.menu = tk.Menu(self.project_menu)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

    def tkraise(self):
        for key, value in self.controller.bit_projects:
            self.project_menu.menu.add_checkbutton(label=key, variable=value)
        tk.Frame.tkraise(self) # call the superclass to actually raise the frame
```